# Как отправить несколько данных и несколько фото одновременно?

Tags: javascript, ajax

у меня есть форма которую я отправляю через jquery, затем улетает в php обработчик, все это сейчас работает. Но мне ко всему этому нужно добавить еще отправку нескольких фото. Как это сделать правильнее? как я понял нужно отправлять через form Data, но как это совместить, вот код.

```js
$(document).ready(function()  {
    $('#reviews_form').submit(function(e) {

        var $form = $(this);
        var rating = $('#rating').val();
        var comment = $('#comment').val();
        var phone = $('#phone').val();
        var plus = $('#plus').val();
        var minus = $('#minus').val();

        var formData = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'reviews-add.php',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) { 
                if (data.includes('error_subscribe')) {
   
                } else { 

                }
            }
        })
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Добавь все в `form_data.append('имя_поля', 'значение_поля')`, потом отправь `data: form_data,`...